# Rebinding Eclipse shortcut to Ctrl+M, Ctrl+U, Ctrl+J, or Ctrl+[ fail

Tags: java, eclipse

I try to rebind some the Eclipse shortcuts to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> fails. The original shortcuts work but if I try to rebind to the ones in list, it will do nothing or behave strangely when I press the shortcut. What's wrong with these shortcuts?

Note, I check the keys and there are no conflicting ones, and I simply change the shortcut and nothing else! I use Eclipse 3.6.

Thanks.

Updated:I managed to get it work. I notice when you want to alter an existing shortcut, you can not define a shortcut that apply to more than one situations, or it will show conflict, but the original shortcut can apply to more than one situation, maybe a nature of Eclipse.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I believe you should be able to bind the same key to different things as long as they are in different contexts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to get it work. I notice when you want to alter an existing shortcut, you can not define a shortcut that apply to more than one situations, or it will show conflict, but the original shortcut can apply to more than one situation, maybe a nature of Eclipse.